# How can I centralize rsyslogs and use as input for logstash?

Tags: linux, logging, logstash, rsyslog

I want to send my rsyslogs from my client servers and use them as input in my logstash, this what I found on web:

on my client I added this lines to my rsyslog.conf :

```
$ModLoad imuxsock

$ModLoad imklog

# Provides UDP forwarding. The IP is the server's IP address
*.* @192.168.1.1:5040 

# Provides TCP forwarding. But the current server runs on UDP
# *.* @@192.168.1.1:5040
```

and added this lines to my server:

```
# provides support for local system logging
$ModLoad imuxsock 

# provides kernel logging support (previously done by rklogd)
$ModLoad imklog

# provides UDP syslog reception. For TCP, load imtcp.
$ModLoad imudp

# For TCP, InputServerRun 514
$UDPServerRun 514

# This one is the template to generate the log filename dynamically, depending on the client's IP address.
$template FILENAME,"/var/log/%fromhost-ip%/syslog.log"

# Log all messages to the dynamically formed file. Now each clients log (192.168.1.2, 192.168.1.3,etc...), will be under a separate directory which is formed by the template FILENAME.
*.* ?FILENAME
```

and restart my rsyslog on both client and server, then in my logstash I described my input like this:

```
input {
  tcp {
     port => 5040
     type => syslog
   }
   udp {
     port => 5040
     type => syslog
   }
}
```

but it doesn't do anything, and when I do control + C it show me this error:

```
SIGINT received. Shutting down the pipeline. {:level=>:warn}
UDP listener died {:exception=>#<IOError: closed stream>, :backtrace=>["org/jruby/RubyIO.java:3682:in `select'", " ...
```

I even use syslog as input in my logstash, but the result was the same.

```
input {
  syslog {
    port => 5040
    type => syslog
  }
}
```

and this the output part of my logstash:

```
output {
  stdout { }
  solr_http {
    solr_url => "http://localhost:8983/solr/logstash_logs"
  }

}
```

what should I do to fix it?

Comment: I can't speak to the syslog side of the problem, but a logstash config with no output{} stanza would qualify as "doesn't do anything".  Do you have a stdout{} output stanza, which will show you what logstash is seeing?

Comment: @AlainCollins yes I have stdout in my output part of logstash, but it doesn't show me anything.I edited my post and added the output part.

Comment: If stdout{} literally doesn't show you anything, then logstash isn't getting any input.

Comment: @AlainCollins thats right, and was because of my firewall!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because of my firewalld and iptables! After I disabled them, everything work as suppose to work!

```
systemctl disable firewalld.service
systemctl disable iptables.service
```